# Android drawable handling based on qualifiers

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-drawable

A friend asked me to help debug her app. The app provides drawables for many types of device configurations.

On Samsung Galaxy Mini, the app crashes, because it can't find any matching resources. (If all resources are copied to `drawable` folder, it fixes the problem.) I'm wondering about the reason of the crash.

The content of the `res` folder is as follows:

[image: Res folder]

The **only** places where actual resources are stored are `drawable-large-tvdpi` and the `drawable-normal-*` folders. The rest of the folders contain only a test image for debug purposes (e.g. `drawable-mdpi` contains a picture with the text 'MDPI', so the app can use it to detect where the current device searches for resources). Obviously, the crash is not due to these debug images, but because the app can't find the actual resources referenced by the app's XML.

The Galaxy Mini has a "small" screen and an "ldpi" density. My guess is that since none of the folders that contain actual resources are for "small" screen size (they either have the "normal" or "large" qualifier), Android will not find any matching resource. (Remember that not all folders store the actual resources.) How should I reorganize everything to *ensure* that the app doesn't crash on any device at all?

(Note that I certainly read the relevant official [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).)

Comment: Of course, I don't want the solution where all resources are also put to "generic folder" like *drawable* (yes, I know, it's same as *drawable-mdpi*). This is because the creator of the app wants to provide pre-generated resources for as many configurations as possible, providing sharp and high-quality in-app images. To sum up, the question is: how should I organize everything by using as few folders as possible, but not risking any crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this gets a little confusing, but the issue is (kind of) articulated in the docs. Specifically:

> Screen pixel density is the one qualifier that is not eliminated due
>   to a contradiction. Even though the screen density of the device is
>   hdpi, drawable-port-ldpi/ is not eliminated because every screen
>   density is considered to be a match [at first].

and

> When selecting resources based on the screen size qualifiers, the
>   system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the
>   current screen if there are no resources that better match (for
>   example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if
>   necessary). However, if the only available resources are larger than
>   the current screen, the system will not use them and your application
>   will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for
>   example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier,
>   but the device is a normal-size screen).

So, the issue is that you are providing density specific resources for normal/large screen qualifiers (e.g. `drawable-normal-ldpi`), but none for small (`drawable-small-ldpi`).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.

Comment: But it was also written in the documentation somewhere "it will scale the drawable in hdpi folder half to use it as ldpi." (I'm not sure where was it.) So what to do now? :/

Comment: The rule only applies to *screen-size*, and not to *density*. Your example is related to screen density. In that case, it can use resources from a higher range.